Use Excel to get only the cycle start date
I have the following data in Excel:



Date
Status of Lab1
Status of Lab2




01-01-2024
On pause
Pausing


02-01-2024
Started
Pausing


03-01-2024
Started
On pause


04-01-2024
Started
On pause


05-01-2024
Pausing
Started


06-01-2024
Pausing
Started


07-01-2024
On pause
Started


08-01-2024
On pause
Pausing


09-01-2024
Started
Pausing


10-01-2024
Started
On pause


11-01-2024
Started
Started


12-01-2024
Pausing
Started


13-01-2024
Pausing
Started


14-01-2024
On pause
Pausing



I want to retrieve the days in which the Lab1 started it's cycle, meaning the 02-01-2024 and the 09-01-2024. Aditionally I want to know the same info for the Lab2. I've been trying with the Index and Match functions but that retrieves me all of the dates where "Started" is true, and I only want the first dates of the cycle, and the cycles don't maintain a constant frequency. Does anyone know how to do this?

You would need to make an algorithm that recognizes a change, i.e., where current status is Started and previous status is not Started. Show your efforts to get help here.

Hey I think i got it using =FILTER($A$2:$A$100;(B2:B100="Started")*(B1:B99<>"Started");"") Don't know if there is a better way though

If you are not using Excel 2010 or Excel 2007 then why tag those versions?

Before providing the required solution, I would like to highlight a few important points based on the tags, particularly regarding the use of Excel 2007. It is important to confirm if you are indeed using Excel 2007, as support for Office 2007 ended on October 10, 2017. Continuing to use this version one can expose to serious and potentially harmful security risks.
While this information is readily available online, it is important to reiterate these risks for your awareness and safety. For more details, please refer to the official documentation and resources provided by Microsoft. MSFT Documentations.

You could try using the following formula, uses a combination of INDEX()+AGGREGATE():


• Formula used in cell E2 --> This is for Lab1
=INDEX($A$2:$A$15,AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW($A$2:$A$15)-ROW($A$2)+1)/
  (($B$2:$B$14<>"Started")*($B$3:$B$15="Started")),ROWS(E$1:E1))+1)


• Formula used in cell E2 --> This is for Lab2
=INDEX($A$2:$A$15,AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW($A$2:$A$15)-ROW($A$2)+1)/
(($C$2:$C$14<>"Started")*($C$3:$C$15="Started")),ROWS(E$1:E1))+1)


NOTE: If you are really using Excel 2010+ then the above formula needs to fill down! But for Excel 2007 one might need to use SMALL() instead of AGGREGATE() function

Alternatively, if have access to FILTER() function then:
• For Lab1:
=FILTER(A2:A15,(B1:B14<>"Started")*(B2:B15="Started"))


• For Lab2:
=FILTER(A2:A15,(C1:C14<>"Started")*(C2:C15="Started"))


Using one single formula can also achieve the output for both the labs:


=WRAPROWS(FILTER(A2:A15,
 (B1:B14<>"Started")*(B2:B15="Started")+
 (C1:C14<>"Started")*(C2:C15="Started")),2)


